# Airflow k8s operator xcom - Handshake status 403 Forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client, airflow

When I run a docker image using **KubernetesPodOperator** in Airflow version 1.10

Once the pod finishes the task successfullly, airflow tries to get the xcom value by making a connection to the pod via k8s stream client.

Following is the error which I encountered:

```
[2018-12-18 05:29:02,209] {{models.py:1760}} ERROR - (0)
Reason: Handshake status 403 Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py", line 249, in websocket_call
    client = WSClient(configuration, get_websocket_url(url), headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/stream/ws_client.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.sock.connect(url, header=header)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 223, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py", line 79, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_handshake.py", line 152, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d %s", status, status_message)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 403 Forbidden
```

> I'm using K8s service account for this

DAG configs

> xcom=true,
>
> get_logs=True,
>
> in_cluster=true

Comment: Hi, we are experiencing the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 8):

So we also hit this problem, we had to modify our rbac rules, in particular we had to add the resource "pods/exec" with the verbs "create" and "get"

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: airflow-runner
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["deployments", "pods", "pods/log", "pods/exec", "persistentvolumeclaims"]
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["singleuser-image-credentials"]
  verbs: ["read","list","watch","create","get"]
```

Comment: Did you also create the `ServiceAccount` and `ClusterRoleBinding`?

Comment: Yes, It's required to have the  ClusterRoleBinding and ServiceAccount to the binding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I run a pod with python script inside kubernetes cluster with another pods running inside. The script try to perform actions over other pods such as `list`, `get` and `exec` command inside the pods. With `exec`, the following ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding works.

`ClusterRole`

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-exec
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

`ClusterRoleBinding`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-exec
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: couchdb
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pod-exec
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Remember to change the name of your `ServiceAccount` and `namespace`.